# CPP MongoDB Driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

Hi I have been trying to use the MongoDB CPP driver but for some reason It creates a lot of errors and only in the specific project I need it in for example in new projects It somehow works and complies perfectly.

I have downloaded the mongocxx driver using vcpkg:

```
cmd> vcpkg install mongo-cxx-driver[boost]:x64-windows
cmd> vcpkg integrate install
```

The errors that I get are:
[image: Errors at VS 2019 while using mongocxx driver]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2039   'count': is not a member of 'mongocxx::mongocxx::v_noabi::options'  MongoDB-Exampels    C:\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\mongocxx\collection.hpp  482 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2039   'bulk_write': is not a member of 'mongocxx::mongocxx::v_noabi::result'  MongoDB-Exampels    C:\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\mongocxx\collection.hpp  257 


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2433   'mongocxx::mongocxx::v_noabi::transaction': 'friend' not permitted on data declarations MongoDB-Exampels    C:\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\mongocxx\read_concern.hpp    151 



Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2039   'aggregate': is not a member of 'mongocxx::mongocxx::v_noabi::options'  MongoDB-Exampels    C:\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\mongocxx\collection.hpp  148
```

and a lot of errors of missing ; or ) but when I lookup the line it doesn't seem to really be the problem...

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Please [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: The problem is I don't get what is the source of the problem as when I write the same code in another project it works....

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution to the problem, I have tried to
Implement this mongodb api in a mt server, so I used winsock2 library for sockets, apparently the error was caused by loading the winsock2 before loading the mongodb library.